# After login button is pressed, redirect to web page in typescript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I am trying to redirect to page after login. Once the login is done, it should redirect to server address. I have tried the preceding codes.

```
var serveraddress = "http://" + server + "/token"/*"/Account/LoginMobile"*/;

   doLogin(): void {

                var username = $("#username").val();
                var password = $("#password").val();
                var server = $("#server").val();
                //TODO do validation

                var serveraddress = "http://" + server + "/token"/*"/Account/LoginMobile"*/;

ApiHelper.post(serveraddress, { username: username, password: password, client_id: "VoltPMS.Mobile", client_secret: "voltrun", grant_type: "password" })
                    .done((data) => {
                        Volt.App.clearLoading();
                        if (data) {
                            if (data.access_token) {
                                SessionManager.setSessionItem("loginstatus", "true");
                                SessionManager.setSessionItem("username", username);
                                //SessionManager.setSessionItem("server", server);
                                SessionManager.setSessionItem("access_token", data.access_token);
                                SessionManager.setSessionItem("refresh_token", data.refresh_token);

                                 $("#username").val("");
                                 $("#password").val("");
                                 //$("#server").val("");
                                 Volt.Navigation.navigate("Home", "Home");
                            } else {
                                //TODO Login Error

                            }
                        } else {
                            //TODO Login ERROR
                        }
                    }).error((er) => {
                    Volt.App.clearLoading();    
                    });
```

How can I redirect this address?

Answer (score -1):

For navigation according to the https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html the best is the The Angular Router component which can by passed in constructor

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

and then used:

`constructor( private router: Router){}
 this.router.navigate(['/home']);`

Comment: I want to redirect "http://" + server + "/token"/*"/Account/LoginMobile"*/;

Comment: I write using typescipt

Comment: Op didnt say they were using Angular. Not everyone wants to use it, and its incredibly hard to find non-angular typescript information on the webs.